# Read Image using httpClient to PictureBox

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to read an image from a web page and to reatrive it inside a picture box.
First question do i need to reatrive it as string or as Base64 format? Or i can save it directly to my picturebox?

```
 string url="xxxx";
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
```

How can i do this? to send it in picturebox?

Comment: You cannot transfer a binary images using http because there are invalid characters in http.  So you must convert to a Base64 string.

Comment: Can i read it directly in base64 format?

Comment: It depends on where the image is located.  If it is embedded in the html file (http format) then it is already in Base64.  If the image is a link to a filename (jpg, png, ...) then it is binary.

Comment: I think that it is binary, i am trying to read from static google map adress string urlmaps = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=

Comment: The Webpage has a picturebox that is getting loaded from a URL link (from a file).  You can either get the URL file and download or try following : http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/02/download-images-from-a-web-page-in-c/